# Why does this query return a money value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I wrote a query that should return an error. Instead, it returns the value 15 with column name `why` and data type `money`.
Do you have an idea why?

```
select \15why
```

Result:

```
why
15.00
```

Comment: Because the yen sign (¥) is a currency indicator, and in some native Japanese character sets, its code point is the same as the one for backslash in ASCII. Basically, it's an obscure way of writing `$15 AS why`, where `AS` is always optional and the parser for currency stops early, not even requiring a space for separation. Nice find!

Comment: I.e. currency indicator, value, column alias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You're specifying a constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql#money-constants):

> money constants are represented as string of numbers with an optional decimal point **and an optional currency symbol as a prefix**

So `select €15` results in a `money` constant, and so does `select $15`, as well as `select ¥15`.

There's a peculiarity as pointed out by [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171409/why-this-query-return-money-type/49171818#comment85348008_49171409):

> Because the yen sign (¥) is a currency indicator, and in some native Japanese character sets, its code point is the same as the one for backslash in ASCII.

See also [MSDN: money and smallmoney (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql).

So `select \15` appears to be equal to `select ¥15`.

As for the column name: `select 5a` results in a column with the alias `a` and a value of `5`. Because "a" is not a numeric suffix, it is treated as `select 5 as a`, where "as" is optional. Instead `select 5e` would return `5` in an unnamed column, because "e" *is* a numeric suffix.

So you've discovered a different way to write `select ¥15 as why`.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm that "\" is being treated as the homoglyph of "¥"?

Comment: @Nisarg I'm trying to find something that confirms that, but am yet unsuccessful.

Comment: I was trying [this](https://gist.github.com/Shah-Nisarg/78f187be27d601ca6daf5877ce55e2d0), but it doesn't anything that maps yen character to the slash. Do you see any problem with the code?

Comment: @Nisarg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS, 0x5C is the Yen character which is a backslash in most other non-Unicode code pages.

Comment: @Nisarg: they're not homoglyphs, it's a code point oddity, and it only occurs in the code that parses money literals. Effectively, it allows the backslash as an undocumented currency indicator. This make some sense, as it always allows all currency indicators regardless of locale -- it would have no effective way (or need) of distinguishing yen/won/backslash for the colliding code points. `SELECT 1 WHERE N'\' = N'¥' COLLATE Japanese_CI_AI` allows you to replicate this for strings, but I doubt that actually hits the same code path.

Comment: The backslash itself oddity is [well documented](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html), along with the weirdness it causes on Windows. SQL Server just piles on an extra oddity by allowing it in currency even when no Japanese collation is involved.