# TSql Preceding Backslash Changes column Value

Tags: sql-server

So, I fat fingered  something when typing my commands and ended up discovering that a preceding backslash before a column name makes the result set return as zeros - for multiple data types.

Why is that?

Screen cap for example:

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure what's going on here (so just a comment), but the SQL language takes some inspiration from old-school BASIC. For example, `<>` instead of `!=` is the standard inequality operator, even if `!=` also works on most platforms. Likewise, \ is the [integer division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dd255271(v=sql.110)). So it seems this interprets things as if you are dividing some unknown numerator by a larger denominator, and with integer division that always works out as `0`.

Comment: I thought / was the division operator not \?

Comment: / is the normal division operator. \ is a special integer division operator, that will always product an integer result, with any decimal portion truncated  (`6.0 \ 5` = `1`, not `1.0` or `1.2`) ...but that documentation link is from Sql Server 2012. I couldn't find anything more recent, and it's specifically omitted from 2017 and 2019 docs... it may not work anymore.

Comment: I dont think division answers our question I just did Version\version and got a syntax error

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with backslash being the escape character?=

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I just tried "select 6.0 \ 5" on several different instances from 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014. That query failed exactly the same way on all of them, with a syntax error. The documentation link you provided is about expressions in SSRS and report builder. It clearly does not actually work in t-sql. Similar to other expressions there like "mod" or "Xor" which are valid in SSRS but not t-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as gleaned from comments is that SQL Server considers a backslash a currency symbol. This can be observed with the results of this query, which returns zero values of type `money`:

```
SELECT \ AS Backslash, ¥ AS Yen, $ AS Dollar;
```

Results:

```
+-----------+------+--------+
| Backslash | Yen  | Dollar |
+-----------+------+--------+
|      0.00 | 0.00 |   0.00 |
+-----------+------+--------+
```

Getting result set metadata using `sp_describe_first_result_set` shows the `money` type is returned:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT \ AS Backslash, ¥ AS Yen, $ AS Dollar;';
```

Results (extraneous columns omitted):

```
+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| is_hidden | column_ordinal |   name    | is_nullable | system_type_id | system_type_name | max_length | precision | scale |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
|         0 |              1 | Backslash |           0 |             60 | money            |          8 |        19 |     4 |
|         0 |              2 | Yen       |           0 |             60 | money            |          8 |        19 |     4 |
|         0 |              3 | Dollar    |           0 |             60 | money            |          8 |        19 |     4 |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

The behavior is especially unintuitive in this case because SQL Server allows one to specify a currency prefix without an amount as a money literal. The resultant currency value is zero when no amount is specified.

[This Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) calls out the general confusion with the backslash and yen mark. This can be observed from SSMS by running the query below to return a backslash string literal. When the results are displayed with font `MS Gothic`, for example, the resultant character glyph is `¥` (yen mark) instead of the expected backslash:

```
SELECT '\' AS Backslash;
```

Results:

```
+-----------+
| Backslash |
+-----------+
| ¥         |
+-----------+
```

Comment: I guess I had already gotten my answer by digging but since this was posted as an answer and explains the issue, I marked it as answered even though technically this is a duplicate quesiton (i think)

Comment: @DougCoats, one can make the argument this is a dup but, in this case, no amount value was specified. I wanted to emphasize the especially confusing behavior when a currency symbol is specified without a value to better help others that might run into this.

Answer (score 3):

It appears `SELECT \` just returns `0.00`. The column name following is added as a label similar to using `AS`. I am not sure why `\` equates to `0.00`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good answer. Also use the `edit` link on the answer to see how I was able to do the formatting for the code and value snippets.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you! Good to know.

Comment: Though this does give me more information, it doesnt totally explain ti for me though. If no one else comes up with something, ill give you the answer.

Comment: @DougCoats I still can't find why \ equates to `0.00` but I have found it can stand in for `0` in math or comparison expressions like `SELECT CASE WHEN 3 > \ THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` returns `1`. I'm fascinated by this and hope you get a more satisfying answer.

Comment: Also `SELECT ISNUMERIC(\)` returns `1`

Comment: `EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT \';` shows a value of zero of data type `money`. Go figure.

Comment: @DanGuzman surprisingly i think this might relate to our issue, which you commented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287368/what-is-the-usage-of-and-in-t-sql

Comment: and of course this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171409/why-does-this-query-return-a-money-value

Comment: AND it appears the real answer may just be buried here http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html

Comment: @DougCoats, the general issue with backslash and a yen currency mark is also called out in this [confusion in usage wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) too. To wit, when I execute `SELECT '\';` in SSMS to return the backslash literal string and display the results with font `MS Gothic`, the yen currency symbol (`¥`) is displayed instead of the expected backslash. SQL Server obviously considers the backslash a currency symbol. These literal specifications all return a zero money value: `SELECT \, ¥, $;`.